# Computation of global error bound for Euler's formula

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, eulers-method, truncation-error

I am trying to calculate the global error bound for Euler's method, but I am having trouble. I am given the formula $|y(t_{i}) - u_{i}| \leq \frac{1}{L}(\frac{hM}{2} + \frac{\delta}{h})(e^{L(t_{i}-a)}-1) +|\delta_{0}|e^{L(t_{i}-a)}$ where $u_{i}$ is the Euler approxmation.  I am also given $M, L, a, \delta, \delta_{0}$, h.  If I am not mistaken this will give me the error for each step, but how do I find the upper bound for the total error?

Comment: Now I understand more.  The total error that I am looking for is really $|y(t_{last}) - u_{last}|$

Comment: $δ$ is the error for evaluating $f$ in floating point, $δ_0$ the rounding error of the initial point?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: You should edit your question to include all relevant information. Some users can guess that the integration starts at time $t=a$ and that $M$ is an upper bound for the second derivative of the solution with respect to time, but not all. You are much more likely to get a good answer if your question is accessible to many people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the error $e_k=|y(t_k)-u_k|$ you get the inequality
$$
e_{k+1}\le e_k+h|f(y(t_k))-f(u_k)|+l_k\le (1+Lh)e_k+l_k
$$
where $l_k$ contains all the local errors, the method step error
$$|y(t_{k+1})-y(t_k)-hf(y(t_k))|\approx \frac{h^2}2|y''(t_k)|,
$$
and the floating point evaluation errors. The recursion inequality can be solved to
$$
e_n \le (1+Lh)^ne_0+\frac{(1+Lh)^n-1}{Lh}\max_{0\le k<n}l_k
$$
Now use $(1+Lh)^n\le e^{Lnh}$ and the bounds for the initial error and the local step errors to get the claimed result. Use the Taylor formula or mean value formula to get proper bounds on the method step truncation error.